# New windows open below visible one

Tags: gnome, 13.10, window, gdm

Every time a new window is opened, gnome likes to force it below the current one so I have to go to the taskbar and restore it.  I can tolerate a lot of stuff but I open new windows way too often (because I'm very wasteful with my screen real estate).

Checked the **Tweak Tool** for possible settings that could be related, only one seemed like it would:

> Whether raising should be a side-effect of other user actions

On or off, same result.

Can't pinpoint anything in `dconf` or `gconf` but theres so much in there I might have missed it.  And can't think of what I might have changed to result in such an awful torture.

Alt-Tab puts it in the very next slot which helps, but I don't always realize a new window is being made (like **Google Hangouts** clicking `Screen Share`)

- **Ubuntu 13.10 x64**
- **Gnome 3.8.4**

  - *using GDM*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the [NoAnnoyance](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1236/noannoyance/) shell extension? It suppresses the "window ready" notification and brings it to the foreground without any user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information and discussion in this bug report: (and possibly upvote and contribute)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1825710